# == operator using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Objects comparison after using reflection

```
var a = new A
   {
      a = "aa",
      b = 1
   };

   var b = new A { 
      a = "aa",
      b = 2
   };

   Type type = typeof(A);

   object old = type.GetProperty("a").GetValue(a);
   object Oldold = type.GetProperty("a").GetValue(b);

   int one = 1;
   int oneOne = 1;

   object oneO = one;
   object oneOneO = oneOne


   // old == Oldold  - true
   // one == oneOne - true
   // oneO == oneOneO - false
}
```

I would expect that oneO == oneOneO is true. Can someone explain me what is going on here?

Comment: From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators) **By default, two reference-type operands are equal if they refer to the same object:**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) the `int` by assigning it to an `Object` variable. That creates a new instance and `==` in `System.Object` compares references, they are different, so it returns `false`.

If you would cast it back(unbox) to an `int` the `==` would work as expected:

```
object oneO = one;
object oneOneO = oneOne;
int newOne = (int) oneO;
int newOneOne = (int) oneOneO;
Console.WriteLine(newOne == newOneOne); // true
```

If you would use `Equals` instead of `==` they would also be compared as expected because `System.Int32` [overrides `Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.equals?view=netframework-4.8#System_Int32_Equals_System_Object_) meaningfully.

- `old` and `Oldold` are reference types(string) which are not boxed, only value types
- But string is a special reference type which overloads the equality operator(read further)

As a rule of thumb: if you use reference types be careful with the `==` operator. `System.String` [overloads the equality operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.op_equality?view=netframework-4.8) for example. But that is an exception. Normally you are just comparing references. Boxing basically makes the value type a reference type, but that's a hidden implementation detail(even `oneO.GetType().IsValueType` still returns `true`).

Also note that this boxing conversion also takes place if you have a method like this:

```
public static bool SameThings(object obj1, object obj2)
{
    return obj1 == obj2;
}
```

I hope you are not anymore surprised that this outputs `false`:

```
Console.WriteLine(SameThings(1, 1));  // false
```

Comment: Also could use `.Equals()` instead of == without unboxing

Comment: Ok, thanks :) That was a warm up. After digging a little bit more in reflection comparisons I have faced another problem: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078896/operator-when-comparing-object-properties-using-reflection