# Why strings stored in object variables and compared with == have this strange behavior?

Tags: c#, reflection

Strange behavior when comparing two string properties with the usage of reflection.

```
var a = new A
{
    X = "aa",
    B = 1
};

var b = new A
{
    X = "aa",
    B = 2
};

Type type = typeof(A);

object aObjValue = type.GetProperty("X")?.GetValue(a);
object bObjValue = type.GetProperty("X")?.GetValue(b);

Console.WriteLine("aObjValue == bObjValue : " + (aObjValue == bObjValue));
Console.WriteLine("aObjValue.Equals(bObjValue) : " + aObjValue.Equals(bObjValue));

a.X = Console.ReadLine();

aObjValue = type.GetProperty("X")?.GetValue(a);

Console.WriteLine("aObjValue == bObjValue : " + (aObjValue == bObjValue));
Console.WriteLine("aObjValue.Equals(bObjValue) : " + aObjValue.Equals(bObjValue));

a.X = "aa";

aObjValue = type.GetProperty("X")?.GetValue(a);

Console.WriteLine("aObjValue == bObjValue : " + (aObjValue == bObjValue));
Console.WriteLine("aObjValue.Equals(bObjValue) : " + aObjValue.Equals(bObjValue));

Console.ReadKey();

//aObjValue == bObjValue : True
//aObjValue.Equals(bObjValue) : True
//aa
//aObjValue == bObjValue : False
//aObjValue.Equals(bObjValue) : True
//aObjValue == bObjValue : True
//aObjValue.Equals(bObjValue) : True
```

When using Console.ReadLine() and manually assigning a.X to "aa" I'm getting `false` but when assigning it in code again I get `true`. This is unexpected behavior for me. Can someone explain me what is going on here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# difference between == and Equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals)

Comment: This is different. We are comparing strings and in both cases but in one case - when using Console.Read() and assigning string manually - output is different

Comment: I have just used different ways to do the same but get different outputs

Comment: This is really about strings being interned in C#, `Console.ReadLine` isn't returning an interned string so it is a completely different object reference. Change it to `string.Intern(Console.ReadLine())` and it should work as you expect. Or even better, don't use `object` in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57074271/operator-using-reflection/57074409#57074409) that string overloads the equality operator `==` to use `Equals`. But since you store them in a `Object` variable they are using the version from `Object` which just compares references.

Again string is a special type, it uses something that is called [string interning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?view=netframework-4.8) to improve performance. So if you use a string literal `"aa"` this will not allocate new memory if there was already a string literal `"aa"`. This is the case here. That is why the first `aObjValue == bObjValue` returns `true`, both are the same reference.

In the second case you enter the string `"aa"` to the console. This will not use string interning(which is a compiler feature), so it is a brand new instance of `String`. That is why the second `aObjValue == bObjValue` returns `false`. If you would cast them to `String` you could use `==` and you would get the expected behavior(same as `String.Equals`).